# Best way to search user/staff by name (first, last or combined) in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, algorithm, sql-server-2008, coldfusion, sql-like

I'm building a query in my system that should take user input and search the `Users` table in my database. There are three different options that I need to filter in my query. First would be if user enters just `John` that is first name, second is if they enter `Miller` that is last name and the third option is if they combine first and last name separated by `comma` or `space` like `John Miller` or `John, Miller`. In our old system the query that was filtering these kind of situations where user enters the name looks like this:

```
<cfif Find(',',arguments.searchFldVal) and ListLen(arguments.searchFldVal) GT 1> <!--- if comma exists --->
    <cfset theLName = Trim(ListGetAt(arguments.searchFldVal,1))>
    <cfset theFName = Trim(ListGetAt(arguments.searchFldVal,2))>
    (
        u_lastName LIKE <cfqueryparam value="#theLName#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
        AND
        u_firstName LIKE <cfqueryparam value="#theFName#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
    )
<cfelseif Find(' ',arguments.searchFldVal) and not find(',',arguments.searchFldVal)><!--- if space exists --->
    <cfset spaceIndex = Find(' ',arguments.searchFldVal)>
    <cfset theFName = Trim(Mid(arguments.searchFldVal,1,spaceIndex-1))>
    <cfset theLName = Trim(Mid(arguments.searchFldVal,spaceIndex+1,len(arguments.searchFldVal)-spaceIndex))>
    (
        u_lastName LIKE <cfqueryparam value="#theLName#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" /> 
        AND
        u_firstName LIKE <cfqueryparam value="#theFName#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" /> 
    )
<cfelse><!--- one word --->
    (
        u_lastName LIKE <cfqueryparam value="#trim(arguments.searchFldVal)#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
        OR 
        u_firstName LIKE <cfqueryparam value="#trim(arguments.searchFldVal)#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
    )
</cfif>
```

The solution above works so far but as you can see that involves using a server side language (that is ColdFusion in my case) to check/search input string for special characters. I'm wondering if there is better way to do this with just using SQL? I have read a few articles and some people proposed an option with `full text search` that I have never used before and I'm not sure if that would be a good fit in this case. The other option is to combine `first` and `last` name and then do the search. Something like this:

```
WHERE u_firstname +' '+ u_lastName LIKE '%#Arguments.searchVal#%'
   OR u_firstname +', '+u_lastName LIKE '%#Arguments.searchVal#%'
```

If anyone has any experience with this type of search algorithm/technique please let me know. I have a few places in my system where I need to implement this and I'm looking for a reliable solution.

Comment: My approach would be that if they didn't know their entire name, they are not worthy.  I suggest 3 text boxes, for first, middle, and last names.  Having said all that, what's your plan for two people with identical names?

Comment: @DanBracuk I have 3 other criteria for search like SysytemID, Username and Email. This is basically last criteria that is offered to them. The problem with having two field is that I would need two input text fields instead of one and I try to avoid that.

Comment: It's reasonable to expect someone to know their email address.  Depending on your situation, it may or may not be reasonable to expect them to know their user name.  If it were me, I'd simply not bother with name searches.

Comment: @DanBracuk I was thinking about that too. Still we might have some people that would like to search by name... Never easy to decide in these situations.

Comment: I would go down the road of the full text search. Especially if I had to search through more than 1000 records

Comment: @James A Mohler can you provide any example?

Comment: Try reviewing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search

Comment: The other thing to remember when using a single box to search 3 names that may be delimited is what's the difference between `john smith`, `john, smith`, `smith, john`, `john q smith`, ....... It will get extremely complicated to search names, especially since you've previously said there are a lot of users.

Comment: @Shawn I thought there is a standard if you put `text, text` that will be considered as `Last Name, First Name` and if you do `text(space)text` that will be considered as `First Name Last Name` the only problem with that is if you have last or first name that has the space.

Comment: That's how it should be. However, never underestimate the ways a user can interact with your interface. I wouldn't give them an either/or. Tell them how you'll accept it and only use that method. And you mentioned a major drawback to searching by entered name.